# Youtube pages are not shown correctly inside the iphone

Tags: iphone, youtube

I have the following problem. When making this call inside a view controller :

[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/user/mc1975mc1/videos?sort=dd&view=0&page=1"]]];

I am getting it correct in the simulator. see the following screen capture:

[image: inside simulator]

But when running on the device, I am getting to separated overlays. See the following pics:

The first one is the left part, the seond one is when starting scrolling while the last one is the second part.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Is it a bug? or there is a way to work around?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the new iOS 6 and the problem solved.

Nobody talked to mee, not any help from apple. But at last it has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

OK.

This is defineitly Apple's bug.

I tested the code with an old 3gs phone and it works perfectly (line the pic of the simulator above).

I will report it to apple.